# Is there a way to compare the data or transactions between 2 oracle database tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

We are using Liquibase to migrate our changes (Oracle) across all our environments. Most Oracle databases have 2 types of tables (transactional and configuration). We are only migrating the data of the configuration tables.

Is there a way for Liquibase (or any other tool) to compare or diff the data changes made in 2 databases (Development DB vs MasterConfig DB)? I just want to understand if this is even possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Developer you have a tool to compare databases:
Tools -> Database Diff

[image]

I'll bet there is something similar in others tools like Toad or PL/Developer.

---

---

---

There is also a tool

DBMS_COMPARISON

There are some details and examples. Maybe it helps.
https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_comparison-identify-row-differences-between-objects

Comment: Thank you for this information. Was wondering if we can use this similar feature during runtime so we can trigger via command line for builds and deployments.

Comment: I added to my answer another tool which could be run from command line. DBMS_COMAPRISON.

Comment: I've updated a typo in @Monika's answer : DBMS_COMPARISON.

Comment: Thanks @Monika - I'm checking this out

Answer (score 1):

The Liquibase diff command can show you the differences and also provide change sets to remediate the delta.

https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/diff.html

Comment: Thanks for this information mate. I thought Liquibase diff is only for comparing database schemas not the transactional data of the tables. I'll have to check it out..

Comment: I'm an idiot. Liquibase does not delta the data, just the structure. My apologies for the snap answer that wasn't completely correct.